# Creating the bar chart in excel

Tags: vbscript

i am trying create a bar chart using the vb script.
my script is

```
Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set objReadWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open("D:\Excel_Macro_Proj\Create_Barchart.xlsx")
Set oExcelReadWorkSheet = objReadWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
objReadWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Activate
objExcel.Visible = True

Sub GraphCreate ()
   ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart2(201, xlColumnClustered).Select
   ActiveSheet.Range("D11:D14,F11:F14,H11:H14")
End Sub
GraphCreate
objReadWorkbook.SaveAs("D:\Excel_Macro_Proj\barchart_create1.xls"),-4143
objExcel.Quit
```

when i run the above macro i am getting an error as, 
"object required ActiveSheet". i am not getting why this error. any one please help me on this.

Answer (score 0):

vbscript cant recognize `ActiveSheet` object directly, it available under `Excel.Application` object..in this case `objExcel.ActiveSheet` and `objExcel.ActiveChart`

Try this code

```
Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set objReadWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open("D:\Excel_Macro_Proj\Create_Barchart.xlsx")
Set oExcelReadWorkSheet = objReadWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
objReadWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Activate
objExcel.Visible = True

Sub GraphCreate ()
   objExcel.ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart2(201, xlColumnClustered).Select
   set xlRange = objExcel.ActiveSheet.Range("D11:D14,F11:F14,H11:H14")
   objExcel.ActiveChart.SetSourceData(xlRange)
End Sub

GraphCreate
objReadWorkbook.SaveAs("D:\Excel_Macro_Proj\barchart_create1.xls"),-4143
objExcel.Quit
```

Comment: Thanks Susilo, it worked perfect. is there any help (any site or document) how we can convert the recorded excel VBA code to VBS code